# Variable doesnt get correct value on react event bus

Tags: reactjs

Hey Guys simple Question,
im trying to set the windowSize variable to the size i get from the event bus,
if i console the size variable i get a number which is fine,
but when i log the WindowSize variable i get undefined,

i figured probably i need to make the function async but i tried and cant figure it out

```
var windowSize
var unsubscribeFunc=  eventBus.on('screenResized', (size)=>windowSize=size)
console.log(" windowSize", windowSize)



function on(eventName, listener) {
    const callListener = ({ detail }) => {
        listener(detail)
    }
    window.addEventListener(eventName, callListener)
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener(eventName, callListener)
    }
}
```